# Number of KPOINTS in irreducible part of Brillouin zone

Tags: vasp, k-points, brillouin-zone

I want to investigate the comparison of Total Energy per cell with respect to the number of `KPOINTS` in the irreducible part of the Brillouin zone but I do not know how to calculate the number of `KPOINTS` with grid size for e.g  3* 3 *3 what will be no. of `KPOINTS` for even or odd no. of k-mesh?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not necessary to care about the total energy versus the number of k points in irreducible reciprocal space, which is closely related to the symmetry of the investigated structure. Of course, you can always read it from `IBZKPT` with a self-consistent run or any other run using VASP. Also, the printed number in `IBZKPT` is related to the [`ISYM`](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ISYM) tag.

I assume what you really care about is the total energy versus k-sampling. About the convergence tests with VASP, namely total energy versus cut-off energy and also versus k-sampling, I strongly suggest you to take a look at this tutorial: https://dannyvanpoucke.be/vasp-tutor-convergence-testing-en/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer . I am following this tutorial for total energy vs k -sampling here no of kpoints in irreducible Brillouin zone has been plotted with respect to total energy but I really do not know how to calculate no .of kpoints for particular grid size to do convergence tests ?

Comment: You can find it in IBZKPT, which is the standard output of VASP.

Comment: Thank you so much yes I found in IBZKPT and many thanks for clearing my doubts .